# Can node red read emails persistently without a refresh time

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am able to use the built in node red email node to read in my gmail inbox no problem. If I set the refresh time below 4 seconds it fails to fetch anything, I am assuming it tries to re-fetch before it finished the first fetch.

I there another way to read in emails that doesn't require any refresh time? Can it just constantly "watch" my email and output anything new into node red?

Comment: Email is meant to be asynchronous, why do you think you need quicker than 4 seconds response time?

Comment: I am using IFTTT and Tasker from my phone to send emails that node red reads and triggers events. For home automation a 4 second delay is not ideal. It works for sure, I am just wondering if its possible to make it quicker. Maybe there is a better way all around to use IFTTT or Tasker to talk to node red than email

Comment: Using HTTP endpoints and port forwarding if you want nearer instant responses

Comment: Would node red monitor these with the HTTP in node?

Comment: https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/create-an-http-endpoint

Comment: I think you'd better use something like [node-red-node-twitter](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-twitter) which can listen to a specific user tweets or searches. I guess you can easily connect IFTTT to Twitter, no ?